# KVO in Swift, funny issue with observeValueForKeyPath

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

I exactly copied the sample in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8) for observing a key value by using the following method:

```
 override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>){
```

Yet the compiler reports that it cannot override the method, funnily presenting the same signature I used.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself by reporting the compiler suggested an alternate form in which the parameters are non-optional, perhaps this is 1.2 Swift format.